# Using a UISegmentedController to insert specific numeric values into an equation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have created a `UISegmentedController` as an addendum to a `UITextField` in order to allow the addition of fractions to the `UITextField` entry. Specifically, I want the `UISegmentedControl` to be able to add 0, .25, .5, or .75 to the user input in UITextField.

For example, user inputs 44 in the `UITextField` and chooses "even", ".25", ".5", or ".75" using the `UISegmentedController`. This total value, say "44.25" will need to be converted to a key to retrieve a corresponding value in a `NSDictionary` to be used in a calculation. I am awaiting clarification on an answer to change the final number to something that can be used in a calculation, but the focus here is how to make a `UISegmentedControl` selection create a value that can be added to my calculation.

I don't have any code, alas, because I am unsure how to create target actions because the different segments don't allow for separate action creation in the way that say, `UIBarButton` items do. When I try to control-click-drag each section, `XCode` wants to create an action for the entire bar.

I am hoping, optimistically, that this doesn't get downvoted into oblivion. I just don't know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: UISegmentedController does not allow you to create separate actions for each segment. If You want to add different value on behalf of segment of UISegmentedController, for that you can use  selectedSegmentedIndex method. It return you index of segment you select and on the basis of index you can get value from array to add in user given value.

Answer (score 0):

A `UISegmented` control has a property, `selectedSegmentIndex`. In the action method for the control, inspect that property to see which segment was selected, and use that for your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your segmentbar with the action called `UIControlEventValueChanged` (Not touchUpInside which used for buttons) for action and this action could be like

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sende
{
      UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
      NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

      if (selectedSegment == 0) {

      }
      else{

      }
}
```

your 4 segment will have index like 0 - 3 which can set your value into dictionary

Comment: OK. So I set the IBAction for the entire UISegmentedControl in .h and then set the above code with an if/ else in .m like `if (selectedSegment == 0) {

      }
      else{selectedSegment == 1

      }else{selectedSegment == 2

      }else{selectedSegment == 3

      }` ?